# Stopping services started by Systemd socket

Tags: linux, systemd

How does Systemd Communicate to socket activated application that the connection has been closed? How can I modify my application to detect this event if it cannot be configured to do so automatically?

We are trying to add network support to legacy code using Systemd sockets. Using [these](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/socket-activation.html) [tutorials](https://gist.github.com/drmalex07/333d8a88c4918954e8e4), we were able to configure a listening TCP port and launch an instance of the application when a connection came in. The problem is that when the connection is closed, the service is still running even though the socket is closed.

The `systemct list-units` and `netstat -tuapn` outputs are what you would expect when the connection is established

```
systemctl list-units:
myapp@5-192.168.0.75:10001-192.168.210.102:19983.service loaded active running   My App

netstat -tuapn:
tcp        0      0 192.168.0.75:10001      192.168.210.102:19983   ESTABLISHED 1/init
```

However, once the client closes the connection, the socket is closed and removed, but the application is still running as a service:

```
systemctl list-units:
myapp@5-192.168.0.75:10001-192.168.210.102:19983.service loaded active running   My App

netstat -tuapn:
[no entry]
```

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related site https://unix.stackexchange.com (Unix & Linux). Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I disagree. The solution is probably going to involved a code change to our application either looking for a signal, incorporating one of the systemd libraries or performing an operation on a given file descriptor. I have edited to primary question to better reflect this stance.

Comment: /opt/foo/serve.py seems a daemon, but in systemd service unit type is simple. This should work if serve.py ends when request or session is handled